# Do the various notions of morphism spaces of simplicial sets agree on the underived level?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ho{Ho}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$There are (at least) seven kinds of morphism spaces for a simplicial set $X$:

1. The [left-pinched morphism space](https://kerodon.net/tag/01KW) $\Hom^L_X(x,y)$,
2. The [right-pinched morphism space](https://kerodon.net/tag/01KW) $\Hom^R_X(x,y)$,
3. The (non-pinched) [morphism space](https://kerodon.net/tag/01J4) $\Hom_X(x,y)$,
4. The simplicial set $\Hom_{\mathfrak{C}[X]}(x,y)$ where $\mathfrak{C}[X]$ is the rigidification of $X$,
5. The simplicial set $\Hom_{\mathfrak{C}^{nec}[X]}(x,y)$ where $\mathfrak{C}^{nec}[X]$ is the [Dugger-Spivak rigidification](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0814) of $X$,
6. The simplicial set $\Hom_{\mathfrak{C}^{hoc}[X]}(x,y)$ where $\mathfrak{C}^{hoc}[X]$ is the simplicial set defined in page 17 of [Dugger-Spivak's Rigidification of quasi-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0814),
7. The simplicial set $\Hom^E_X(x,y)$ defined in page 15 of [Dugger-Spivak's Mapping spaces in Quasi-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0469).

Do these mapping spaces all agree on the "underived level"? I.e. do we have
$$
\pi_0\Hom^L_X(x,y)\cong\pi_0\Hom^R_X(x,y)\cong\pi_0\Hom_X(x,y)
$$
$$\cong\pi_0\Hom_{\mathfrak{C}[X]}(x,y)\cong\pi_0\Hom_{\mathfrak{C}^{nec}[X]}(x,y)\cong\pi_0\Hom_{\mathfrak{C}^{hoc}[X]}(x,y)
$$
$$
\cong\pi_0\Hom^E_X(x,y)
$$
for an *arbitrary* simplicial set $X$?

In particular, is this true in the special case where $x=y$? (<s>Such a restriction helps already for the left/right pinched morphism spaces: by [Tag 01KZ](https://kerodon.net/tag/01KZ), we have $\Hom^L_X(x,x)\cong\Hom^R_X(x,x)^\mathrm{op}$, and thus $\pi_0\Hom^L_X(x,x)\cong\pi_0\Hom^R_X(x,x)$ since $\pi_0(X^\mathrm{op})\cong\pi_0(X)$.</s> **Edit: this is wrong, see R. van Dobben de Bruyn's answer below**)

Comment: I thought the first issue is that $\pi_n$ doesn't really make sense if $X$ isn't a Kan complex. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cheyne The definition of the $\pi_n$ of a Kan complex does not make sense for a general simplicial set since homotopy [can fail to be an equivalence relation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+homotopy#properties), but $\pi_0$ works okay, being given by $\mathrm{colim}(X)\cong\mathrm{Coeq}(X_0\rightrightarrows X_1)$. The motivation I had in mind for this question is that one could perhaps define higher homotopy groups* for general simplicial sets by letting $\Omega X=\mathrm{Hom}_X(x,x)$, and then considering $\pi_0(\Omega\cdots\Omega X)$. (*They will be just sets in general)

Comment: The one big problem for this definition however would be if $\pi_0\mathrm{Hom}_X(x,x)$ didn't agree with $\pi_0\mathrm{Hom}^L_X(x,x)$ or $\pi_0\mathrm{Hom}^R_X(x,x)$.

Comment: (It's also worth mentioning that $\pi_0$ of the endomorphism spaces can behave in [unexpected ways](https://mathoverflow.net/a/177834) for general simplicial sets because of their "directedness", e.g. $\pi_1(\partial\Delta^2)$ defined as above is a point, while $\pi_1$ of the geometric realization of $\partial\Delta^2$ (which is a circle) is $\mathbb{Z}$ (this makes sense though: the $\pi_0$ of the category "that looks like" $\partial\Delta^2$ is again just a point.)

Comment: N.B. #4 and #5 are weak homotopy equivalent for every simplicial set $X$. (This is one of the main theorems of the Dugger--Spivak paper.)

Comment: Thank you, @Emily!

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Thanks! Just to be sure, does this mean that the $\pi_0$'s of #4 and #5 will agree after taking $Ex^\infty$ but may otherwise differ? (Also checking their paper again, I noticed I forgot to include the $\mathfrak{C}^{\mathrm{hoc}}$ functor from there. There really are a lot of variant notions of morphism spaces for simplicial sets! )

Comment: @cheyne It's my pleasure! Thank you too! =)

Comment: @Emily It implies that their $\pi_0$'s are isomorphic (even before applying $Ex^\infty$, which doesn't alter the $\pi_0$ of a simplicial set).

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Thanks for the clarification! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no hope of comparisons between $\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}^L_X(x,y)$ and $\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}^R_X(x,y)$ in general, even when $x=y$. (Note that the statement you cited says $\operatorname{Hom}^L_{X^{\text{op}}}(x,x) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_X^R(x,x)^{\text{op}}$, so it computes Homs in a different simplicial set.)

**Example.** Let $X$ be the coequaliser of $f,g \colon \Delta^0 \amalg \Delta^1 \rightrightarrows \Delta^2$, where $f$ maps $\Delta_0$ to $0$ and $\Delta^1$ to $\operatorname{id}_0$, and $g$ maps $\Delta_0$ to $2$ and $\Delta^1$ to the arrow $0 \to 1$. The nondegenerate simplices in $X$ are:

- A single vertex $x$ (the image of $0$, $1$, and $2$ in $\Delta^2$).
- Two arrows $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (the images of $0 \to 2$ and $1 \to 2$; the third arrow $0 \to 1$ has become identified with a degenerate $1$-simplex).
- One $2$-simplex $h$ (the image of $0 \to 1 \to 2$), by definition a right homotopy $\alpha \stackrel\sim\to \beta$.

Thus we see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are right homotopic (hence homotopic in $\operatorname{Hom}_X(x,x)$ as well), but not left homotopic as there are no other nondegenerate $2$-simplices. $\square$

In particular, any of the definitions that are self-dual (e.g. $\operatorname{Hom}_{X^{\text{op}}}(x,y) = \operatorname{Hom}_X(y,x)^{\text{op}}$) cannot agree with $\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}^L_X(x,y)$ or $\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}^R_X(x,y)$ in general. For instance, if $\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}^L_X(x,y) = \pi_0\operatorname{Hom}_X(x,y)$ for all $X$, then
\begin{align*}
\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}_X^R(x,y) &= \pi_0\operatorname{Hom}_{X^{\text{op}}}^L(y,x)^{\text{op}} = \pi_0 \operatorname{Hom}_{X^{\text{op}}}(y,x)^{\text{op}} \\
&= \pi_0 \operatorname{Hom}_X(x,y) = \pi_0 \operatorname{Hom}_X^L(x,y),
\end{align*}
which we saw is false (again feel free to assume $x=y$).

I believe all the others are self-dual (but I'm not familiar with all of them), so at least they don't agree with $\pi_0\operatorname{Hom}_X^L(x,y)$ or its dual. I'm not sure if any subset of the others agree in general, but you can probably make counterexamples like the one above. (The convenient coincidence is that finite simplicial sets are far removed from the Kan or inner horn conditions: from some dimension on, you can only produce degenerate simplices, which do a bad job filling horns.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is precisely what I was looking for!